# Why won't my xmodmap command run on startup/login?

Tags: ubuntu, login, startup

I want to run this command every time I log in (or every time I start up, if that doesn't work): `xmodmap -e 'keysym Delete = Menu' -e 'keysym Menu = Delete'`

I've tried many things. I put the command in `System > Preferences > Startup Applications`. I put it in a `.sh` file, marked it `chmod +x` and put that file in `System > Preferences > Startup Applications`. I put the script in `/etc/init.d`. I put the commands in `~/.profile`. Nothing seems to work.

Finally, I put this in my `~/.profile`:

```
touch test1
xmodmap -e 'keysym Delete = Menu' -e 'keysym Menu = Delete'
touch test2
```

Both test1 and test2 get created, but the keys are still not remapped. If I just copy/paste the command and run it manually, it works fine. But it won't run on login. Any ideas?

Comment: don't post [the same question](http://superuser.com/questions/185345/why-wont-my-xmodmap-command-run-on-startup-login) on multiple Stack Exchange sites (unless the question is on-topic on both sites *and* you've waited a long time and not had any good answer on the first site; but then include a link to the original question).

Comment: @Gilles: Is that the official policy? It seems like if it is on-topic on both sites, then both sites can benefit from it. But if this has already been discussed and decided, I will be careful in the future.

Comment: I thought there was an official FAQ entry about this, but I can't find it. I've [asked on meta](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/146/policy-on-multiposting).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on your distribution the `~/.xsession` file is executed (a shell script) when logging into X. And/or the `~/.Xmodmap` file is sourced by an `xmodmap` process.

The `~/.profile` file is only executed by a login shell (with or without X), thus it is not the right place

Answer (score 6):

Put it in `~/.Xmodmap`. Some distro look for `~/.Xmodmap` instead of `~/.xmodmaprc`. It works for me on Fedora 16.

Comment: This is the best solution on debian

Answer (score 1):

Put it in `~/.xsessionrc` and make sure that `/etc/X11/Xsession.options` contains `allow-user-xsession`.