# run xmodmap commands after login

Tags: xorg, login, xmodmap, session

I created a file `~/.Xmodmap` with my mapping commands. I thought that it will be automatically launched after login (and restart) but it's not. So I have to always run after login the command

`$ xmodmap .Xmodmap`

Is it possible to automatize this process?

thank you

Comment: Whatever solution you are trying out, use **absolute path** to your scripts. This worked for me: https://askubuntu.com/a/54194/591187 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but exactly how depends on which shell you're using.

In case of `bash`, edit `~/.bashrc` and add a line saying
`xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap`

If you don't have a `~/.bashrc` yet, create one and start it with

```
#!/bin/bash 
if [ -f /etc/bash.bashrc ] ; then
    . /etc/bash.bashrc
fi 

xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap
```

If you're using a different login shell such as `tcsh` or `dash` or `zsh`, you'll need to  check its manpage to see what files it reads and executes on startup and add the command there. If you're unsure what login shell you're using, the `SHELL` environment variable should have been set, and you can check that instead with `echo $SHELL` .

EDIT: My bad. `~/.xsession` is the correct file to add this.

Comment: Additional question for fellow helpers: Given that not all terminal emulators default to a login shell I recommended `.bashrc` rather than `.bash_profile`; if there's a persuasive argument for keeping it restricted to login shells I'd like to hear it.

Comment: I'm using `bash`. Maybe I asked the question bad way. I edited `~/.bashrc` as you said and restarted the computer and after restart I had to run `xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap` manually to have remapped keys.

Comment: Try adding the line to `~/.bash_profile` as well, as `~/.bashrc` may not get loaded in a login shell.

Comment: This helped. I had to create the file `~/.bash_profile` . Should I add all the lines or only the one line with `xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap`?

Comment: This worked for a while but stopped working and I had to run it manually again.

Comment: `.bashrc` is aboslutely not the right place. It is read when you start an interactive shell. It is not read when you start a graphical environment, but it will be read each time you open a terminal window. In other words, it won't trigger when it should, and will trigger when it shouldn't.

Comment: My bad. Which is, then? `.xsession`?

Comment: @Shadur: Should it be `.xsession` or `.xsessionrc`? The one I linked to mentions both.

Comment: According to http://www.acm.uiuc.edu/workshops/cool_unix/xinitrc.html it's either `.xinitrc` or `.xsession` depending on how you start X -- if you use gdm or kdm or the like, it's the latter, if you use `startx` from the command line it's the former.

Comment: `$ ps aux | grep X`
`root       619  1.7  1.1  30772 22908 tty7     Ss+  07:50   0:34 /usr/bin/X :0 -br -verbose -auth /var/run/gdm/auth-for-gdm-WDyyFH/database -nolisten tcp vt7
xralf   946  0.0  0.0   1832   536 ?        Ss   07:51   0:00 /bin/sh /etc/xdg/xfce4/xinitrc -- /etc/X11/xinit/xserverrc
xralf  1073  0.0  0.5  50228 12244 ?        S    07:51   0:00 /usr/lib/xfce4/panel-plugins/xfce4-menu-plugin socket_id 27263015 name xfce4-menu id 1 display_name Xfce Menu size 24 screen_position 11`
so, I think I'm using startx? Should I create the file `~/.xinitrc`?

Comment: From the looks of it, you're using gdm. Like I said, the easy way to check is whether you use a graphical login screen or whether you start with a command prompt -- and if you have to ask, you're *likely* using gdm. So `.xsession`

Comment: OK, I pasted the row into `.xsession`. I will give it few days time. thank you

Answer (score 3):

I was looking through old questions here just last night for this issue. [This post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1677/why-wont-my-xmodmap-command-run-on-startup-login) suggests putting the `xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap` line in `~/.xsessionrc` and making sure `/etc/X11/xsession.options` contains the line `allow-user-xsession`.

I haven't rebooted since then to test it, however.

Comment: It works after restart. I will wait for a while yet because Shadur's answer worked after restart too.

Comment: Now, I restarted and it doesn't work.

Comment: Check out Shadur's comments to his answer; the filename may need to be .xinitrc or .xsession instead.