# xmodmap in xsession running without effect

Tags: desktop-environment, xmodmap

Following this other [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11604/run-xmodmap-commands-after-login) I put this in my `.xsession` file

```
date -I > /tmp/xsession_started
xmodmap -e "pointer = 3 2 1" &> /tmp/mouser.log
```

I can see the `xsession_started` file is created successfully:

```
cat /tmp/xsession_started          
2020-07-29
```

And the `xmodmap` ran and left a log:

```
cat /tmp/mouser.log  
Warning: Only changing the first 3 of 10 buttons.
```

Yet, my mouse is still right handed (the `xmodmap` should have swapped the buttons out and made it a lefty).

So what is going on here?  Is the environment somehow 'before' my actual xsession?

My desktop environment happens to be LXQt this morning, but the same happens when I login to others as well.

**EDIT:**

Actually KDE and GNOME respect the `.xsession` setting, it appears to be the 'lesser' environments like LXQT and LXDE, etc. that don't.

Comment: Does `xmodmap -e "pointer = 3 2 1"` work in the first place if you try it in your X session? If yes, can you try a sleep? I.e., `sleep 3; xmodmap -e "pointer = 3 2 1" &> /tmp/mouser.log`.

Comment: it definitely works in my xsession, and in fact it works when I boot into plasma and gnome, just not LXQT for some reason.