# Xmodmap on bashrc not working

Tags: bash, linux-mint, login, xmodmap, synclient

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why won’t my xmodmap command run on startup/login?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1677/why-wont-my-xmodmap-command-run-on-startup-login)

I have my `.bashrc` file with the three following commands:

```
xmodmap ~/.xmodmap
synclient TapButton2=2
synclient ClickFinger2=3
```

They are supposed to execute when I log in, right? But the changes do not happen in my system (LInux Mint 12) unless I open a terminal window which will execute those commands again.

I would like to perform those commands when I log in and to remove then from bashrc, so I put them on `.profile` but they also keep not changing the behavior from my keyboard and touchpad.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `.bashrc` is read when you open a terminal. `.profile` is read when you log in in text mode; depending on your distribution, it may or may not also be read when you log in in graphical mode. See [Alternative to .bashrc](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3052/alternative-to-bashrc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`xmodmap` only does anything once you are already *in* an X session (because it has to make calls to the X server), and neither `~/.bashrc` (nor `~/.profile`) guarantee that, nor will they be automatically executed once you enter an X session. You need to put it into your startup configuration.

If you are using `startx` or `xinit` to launch X, put this in `~/.xinitrc`. If you're using something else, look at your documentation to find out where you should put startup applications.

Comment: Well, I made a small shellscript with those commands and put it to run via Mint's GUI. Thanks for your help.