# .xsession executed on login in Linux Mint Cinnamon

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon, xmodmap

I've put a command to change my keyboard mapping in .xession, but this does not appear to be executed on login in Cinnamon, although it seems to work fine on an older MATE box.

Since first asking this question I've tried these places, all of which don't work:

- .profile
- .Xmodmap and .xmodmap
- .xinputrc
- .xession

Where is the preferred place to put this command to be executed on login in Cinnamon?

Answer (score 0):

~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, and ~/.profile all appear to be read at login, but based on another question, they don't appear to be able to run xmodmap reliably.

Although it's maddening, the only way I've been able to resolve this is to add a script as a start up item.

- [Xmodmap on bashrc not working](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55848/xmodmap-on-bashrc-not-working)
- https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Startup-Files